# Is there an awamori distillery/factory/etc in Okinawa that does tours or allows visitors, with tasting/samples?

Tags: japan, sightseeing, alcohol, okinawa

Here in Okinawa there is a local spirit called 泡盛 *awamori*.

It is completely distinct from sake (and from shochu). It's only made on the islands of Okinawa, and there are very many kinds for sale.

So far the locals I have asked don't know whether there's an awamori manufacturer that tourists can visit.

I don't mind where it is, as long as it's on the main island of Okinawa. I do want a place that offers samples or tastings and doesn't mind that you're not buying. I'm not expecting them to get me drunk `(-;` I'd prefer a place that's used to lots of tourists I think, where I wouldn't have to arrange something in advance and where I wouldn't be putting the out by asking for special favours.

Oh and I don't really want a paid tour with an outside company, just us going to the factory on our own but we don't mind if other tourists are there too. Something like "cellar doors" in wine-growing areas or like in tequila/mezcal making areas of Mexico ...

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be at least a couple!

[**Chuko** Awamori](http://www.chuko-awamori.com/) in Tomigusuku apparently has [free tours](http://www.okinawastory.jp/en/view/portal/0111017100/).

It's about a twenty minute drive from the airport. I'm not sure if they offer free tasting as the webpage mentions prices for buying awamori, but this doesn't mean there's not also free sipping.

Apparently this is the only company that makes its own earthenware awamori storage jars, which are used for aging.

The company also has [its own page about their tours](http://www.chuko-awamori.com/newfactory/), but it seems to only be in Japanese.

---

Another seems to be **[Zuisen](http://www.zuisen.co.jp/e/index.html)** in Shuri, not far from the main UNESCO castle in Okinawa. From their website:

> Tours of Zuisen Distillery (every 30 minutes from 9:30 to 16:30)
>   The distillery is an approximately 10-minute walk from Shurijo Castle as well as from Yui-rail Shuri Station.
>   Feel free to visit us while sightseeing or wandering around the area.
>   *Reservations are necessary for groups of 10 or more.

---

I cannot find a central/unified site listing all distilleries, but there are a few pages listing one or two:

- [OkinawaIndex.com](http://www.okinawaindex.com/index/?tid=2&cid=250&id=1) lists Zuisen and **Sakumoto**, the latter only by reservation.
- [OkinawaStory.jp](http://www.okinawastory.jp/en/search/portal/see/plant/) lists Zuisen, **Kamimura**, **Mizuho**, and Chuko.